# SSRS - Exported Excel Worksheet Links

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report that creates 9 different worksheets in a workbook. I'd like to make the first tab a table of contents where each item links to a specific worksheet. I know I can do this manually in Excel after I export the report, but I was hoping to find a more automated method.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a document map and this will be rendered as an index page in your Excel file.

I'm assuming that your separate each sheet by grouping your data in which case just right click the group then `properties` then `Advanced` and set the `Document map` expression to whatever you want the index labelled as (probably the same field as you group with).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've yet to create a document map in SSRS so I will take a look at that. My sheets aren't separated by grouping, but rather they are subreports inside rectangles and each rectangle has a page break after it so that it spits it onto its own worksheet.